# gdb debugging std::list<> - how to traverse the list?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

What's the strange internal layout of std::list<> for traversal?
When i use a python helper like this:

```
def invokeCore(self, headlines, data, valueType, valueHandler):
    
    valueType = gdb.lookup_type (valueType)
    
    head = data['_M_impl']['_M_node'].address
    current = data['_M_impl']['_M_node']['_M_next']
    
    no = 0
    while current != head:
        realData = current.cast(valueType)
        if realData.address != 0:
            valueHandler(no, realData)
        else:
            print('### PrintGenericList::invokeCore(): failed downcast for list node')

        current = current['_M_next']
        no += 1

    return ''
```

Then the 1st entry printed by the callback 'valueHandler' is empty and the last entry is missing.
According another reference here: https://github.com/johnathan79717/gdb-stl-view/blob/master/.gdbinit
there is used

```
p **($arg1**)($current + 1)
```

But what's this ($current **+ 1**) there?
When $current is initialized

```
set $current = $arg0._M_impl._M_node._M_next
```

?

Answer (score 3):

First, the macros you linked to are no longer reliable.  I tested using std::list with GCC 9.3.1 and `plist` doesn't work correctly, so don't rely on them too much for guidance.

However, what those macros are trying to do is to bodge around the types used to store data within the list.

Consider, this GDB session where `my_list` is a `std::list<int>` containing 3 elements:

```
(gdb) p/r my_list
$1 = {
  <std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {
    _M_impl = {
      <std::allocator<std::_List_node<int> >> = {
        <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<int> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
      members of std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_List_impl:
      _M_node = {
        <std::__detail::_List_node_base> = {
          _M_next = 0x416eb0,
          _M_prev = 0x416ef0
        }, 
        members of std::__detail::_List_node_header:
        _M_size = 3
      }
    }
  }, <No data fields>}
(gdb) ptype my_list._M_impl._M_node 
type = struct std::__detail::_List_node_header : public std::__detail::_List_node_base {
  public:
    std::size_t _M_size;

    _List_node_header(void);
    _List_node_header(std::__detail::_List_node_header &&);
    void _M_move_nodes(std::__detail::_List_node_header &&);
    void _M_init(void);
  private:
    std::__detail::_List_node_base * _M_base(void);
}
(gdb) ptype my_list._M_impl._M_node._M_next 
type = struct std::__detail::_List_node_base {
    std::__detail::_List_node_base *_M_next;
    std::__detail::_List_node_base *_M_prev;
  public:
    static void swap(std::__detail::_List_node_base &, std::__detail::_List_node_base &);
    void _M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base *, std::__detail::_List_node_base *);
    void _M_reverse(void);
    void _M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base *);
    void _M_unhook(void);
} *
(gdb) p *my_list._M_impl._M_node._M_next 
$7 = {
  _M_next = 0x416ed0,
  _M_prev = 0x7fffffffad40
}
```

So, `_M_node` is a `_List_node_header`, which links to a `_List_node_base`, which links to further `_List_node_base` until, eventually, we link back around to `_M_node`, which indicates the end of the list.

You handle this in your code with the `while current != head:` loop.

The question then, is where is the data stored?  Turns out that the things that `_M_next` point too are not `_List_node_base` objects, but are instead `std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Node`, which looks like this:

```
(gdb) ptype std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Node
type = struct std::_List_node<int> [with _Tp = int] : public std::__detail::_List_node_base {
    __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<_Tp> _M_storage;
  public:
    _Tp * _M_valptr(void);
    const _Tp * _M_valptr(void) const;
}
```

Notice, this is a sub-class of `_List_node_base`.  So, if we throw in an appropriate cast, we can see this:

```
(gdb) p *(std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Node *) my_list._M_impl._M_node._M_next 
$2 = {
  <std::__detail::_List_node_base> = {
    _M_next = 0x416ed0,
    _M_prev = 0x7fffffffad40
  }, 
  members of std::_List_node<int>:
  _M_storage = {
    _M_storage = "\003\000\000"
  }
}
```

Now it becomes clearer what the GDB macros you linked are trying to do, when they say `$current + 1` the `$current` is an `_M_next` pointer, and is of type `_List_node_base`.  The `+ 1` will skip forward the size of one `_List_node_base` which steps over the `_M_next` and `_M_prev` pointers, we're then looking at the `_M_storage` from the sub-class.

The `**($arg1**)($current + 1)` then just treats the `_M_storage` as a pointer to a pointer to the list element type, and then tries to dereference that and grab the list value.  This is the bit that doesn't work for me any more, as the `int` values are stored into the `_M_storage` buffer directly, rather than having a pointer to the object placed in the buffer, it seems like GCC is more optimal here than it used to be, but this means you need to be smarter fetching values from the list.

Which is why I started by saying those macros were a bodge.  None of the above is really reliable at all.  I notice that the comments in the macros talk about GCC 4.x, so maybe this didn't seem so bad back then, but it really isn't great now.

So, what should you do next?  Well, for printing std::list I would suggest trying to use GCC's existing pretty printers.  Most distros should have a package that includes these, and GDB should load them automatically.  With these in place:

```
(gdb) p my_list
$14 = std::__cxx11::list = {
  [0] = 3,
  [1] = 4,
  [2] = 5
}
```

But, if you really want to learn how to walk the STL data structures for printing, then I'd suggest [you read the GCC source for their pretty printers](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py), these should give a much more reliable source of knowledge.

Comment: HI Andrew, thanks for your help, and sorry for my late response.
With help of your manual exercise above, i found out, how i have to change my implementation. The https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py is using iterators. I will switch to that asap, because it more compatible. But for the time being i can adapt my approach to consider that the last node, which points to head again is also containing the last payload item of the list.

I'll post the result as another answer here.